# modify filter with num?

Tags: python, numpy, filter

I want to try and modify my sepia method, I have a sepia matrix

But I want the user to give a value between 0 and 1 to adjust the matrix, Im not sure how to apply this this n value to the matrix, which values should be multiplied with the matrix.

I start by user giving the value 0, which will proved the identity matrix

Any hints on what and how to multiply the identity matrix with n?
If n is 1 it should return the sepia_matrix over

Comment: I mean, you could literally just multiply the matrix by `n`. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to apply the filter from an image?

Comment: @mozway yes i will do it now

Comment: You need to show some examples of user input and the expected output. There are all sorts of ways you could adjust this matrix given some number n. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @kwinkunks I posted the input, it will be an array of a image and how the filter will work, by @ the matrix.T. What I want is the new matrix deppending on n

Comment: Right, so what do you want the result to be if n = 0 or if n = 0.5? What does "the sepia_matrix over" mean? Does this mean n = 1 should return the input matrix unchanged? When you say you want the identity matrix, do you mean you want the sepia_matrix to leave the input image unchanged, or do you mean that you want the sepia_matrix to be unchanged? Provide specific examples of input and output.

Comment: avoid naming your variable with a native function name. Here, ```open``` is not a very good choice for a variable, since it is the name of a native function to open files.

Comment: Are you trying to impact the "intensity" of sepia filter. Meaning, n=0 ⇒ image is unchanged, n=1 ⇒ image is what "im" is in your example (image times sepia filter), and n=0.5 ⇒ sepia filter is halfway applied (visually, image has more color) ?

Comment: If so, you could just computed the weighted average of your original image and the sepia version ```(n*im + (1-n)*arr)```

Comment: Or, more efficiently (but mathematically it is the same), do so for the matrix: ```M=n*sepia_array + (1-n)*np.identity(3)```. And then ```im=arr @ M.T```

Comment: @feter I get such artifacts with your original code as well (just the normal sepia matrix)

Comment: Maybe provide a test image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that you want to interpolate between the identity matrix and your own matrix in a meaningful way. It has already been suggested to use

```
interp_matrix = (1-t)*np.identity(3) + t*sepia_matrix
```

This would definitely work to some degree, but I'd argue you should use a multiplicative interpolation, so use

```
interp_matrix = scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power(sepia_matrix, t**p)
```

Where `p` is e.g. 2 or 4 or so, depending how "quickly" you want the interpolation to happen.

Both of them are the identity matrix for `t=0` and your `sepia_matrix` for `t=1`, but I think the latter would be more natural. Not

Comment: Last line your read "identity matrix for t=**0** and your sepia_matrix for t=1, I surmise.

Comment: Anyway, I agree with the suggestion. It is obviously better than linear interpolation. And would work even with negative value (to "unsepia" as far as possible an image, assuming that it was "seppied" with that sepia_matrix), and >1 value (t=2 meaning applying the filter twice

Comment: The only virtue of linear interpolation is that it is easy to understand, and my goal was to ask the OP whether this was what they were trying to do